# Area under the graph is not the integral when the measure is not $\sigma$-finite?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

It can be shown, for a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ on a measurable spaces $X$, the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $[0,+\infty)$, and a measurable function $f:X\to [0,+\infty)$, that:
$$\int_X f(x) d\mu= \mu\times\lambda\ (E)$$
Where $E=\{(x,t): t<f(x)\}$ is the 'area under the graph' of $f$.

If we drop the $\sigma$-finiteness of $\mu$, what is a possible counter example?

It seems like we can drop that condition and still get away with $+\infty=+\infty$ . 
Or I am missing some 'weird' non-$\sigma$-finite measure.

$\textbf{EDIT}$: $\mu\times \lambda$ is not well defined when $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite, then what is a counter example for the following useful equality:
$$\int_X f(x) d\mu= \int_0^{+\infty} u(\{x: f(x)>t\})\,dt$$

Comment: The definition I know for $\mu\times\lambda$ makes sense only for $\sigma$-finite measures. So does the question even make sense?

Comment: I just checked, it exists for non $\sigma$-finite measures but the uniqueness is not guaranteed. So $\mu\times\lambda$ can denote different measures. We would then need a counter-example where none of them is equal to the integral.

Comment: yes, I am looking for such an example. And why can't we make sense of $\mu\times \lambda$ when $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: I edited the question to add one equality, will the right hand side be not defined if $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite? is $t\mapsto \mu(\{x:f(x)>t\})$ not always measurable?

Comment: You define $\mu\times\lambda$ such that $(\mu\times\lambda)(A\times B)=\mu(A)\lambda(B)$. For $\sigma$-finite measures there exists only one such product measure. If we drop the $\sigma$-finiteness then uniqueness is not guaranteed, so it's not that $\mu\times\lambda$ does not exists, it is that it could mean different measures.